# How to get rid of duplicate tweets on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

[image]I keep seeing the same tweet over and over again... it's really annoying... making the service basically unusable. I'm following financial news like Bloomberg and WSJ... and I see the same tweet from them over and over again.

Is there a setting to turn the duplicate off? Why is it duping?

Comment: Are you seeing original post again over again or they tweeting same thing again n again?

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like a new tweet because the link to the article is different. But it's the same article.

Comment: If its a new tweet then it will always appear even if it is having same content.

Comment: Please post a screenshot to help us understand this problem better!

Comment: @SleepingGod. Here you go.

Comment: The user is tweeting the same thing again and again (as shown by the time difference) I'm sorry you can't really do much in this situation apart from unfollow them or DM them asking them to stop exactly repeating their posts.